# What does this message say?

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I have a very... odd... friend.

We were talking the other day and I texted him asking him his favourite food. He replied with the following:

> ```
> AAABAABBABABBAAAABBABAAAAAAAAABAABABAABBABABAAAAAABAABAABAAAABBABABBAABAAABBABBAABBABBAABBAABBBAAAAABAAB
> BAABAABAAABABBABABABABAABBAABAAAAABBBAABAAABBBAABAAAABABABAAABAAAABAAABBAABABAAABBAABAAABAAABBBAABBAAAAB
> AABABABBAABABAAAAAABAAABABBABBABBAABBAABAABAABAAABBBABAAABAAABABABBAABAABAAABBAAABAAAAAAABBAAABAAAAAAAAB
> BAAAAABBBAABBBAAABAABAAAAAAAABABBABBABABBAAABBABBAAABABBBAAAAAAAAABAAABAAAAABBAABABABBABABBAABAABAABAAAA
> BBAABAAABABAAABABBBAABAABAAABABAAABABABABBABABBAABAABAAABBBAABAABAAAAAABAABAAABBAABABAABAAABBBAABAAABABA
> ABAAAABBAAAABAAABABAAABAAABBAAAABBABAABAAABBBABAAABAAABABBABABBAAAABAAAABBBBAABBABBAAAAABBBAAAAAABAAAAAB
> BAAAAAABBAAAAABBBAABABABAAAABAAABBAABAABABABBAABAAABAABABABAAABAAAABABAABABAAABBBAABAAABABAABBBABAAAAAAB
> AAABBBAABABAAAAAAAAABAABAAAABBAAAABBAAAABABABAAABAAABAABAAABBBAAAAABAAABABBBAAAAAAAAABAAABAAAABABBAAAAAA
> AAAABBAAAAABAAABAAABAAABAAABAAAABAAAAAAAABAABAABABBABABBAAABBAAABBABAAABAAAAAAAAAABABAAABAAABABAAAABBAAB
> AAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCBBBCCCBBBBCCBBBCCCBBBCCCBBBBCCBBBCCCBBBBCCCCCCBBCCCBBBCCCBBBBCCCC
> CBBBCCCCBBCCCCBBBCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCCBACCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCB
> CCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCCBCCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCCAACCBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBCCCBCCBCCBBBBCCBBB
> CCCBBBBCCCCCBBBBCCBBBCCCBBBBCCCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCBCBCCCBCCCBBBBCCBCBCBCCCABCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBC
> CBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBCCBCCBBCCCBACCB
> BBCCCBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBCCCBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBBBCCCBCCBCCCBBBCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBCCBCC
> BCCBCCCBCBCAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBCCSSSSCCBBBBBCCCBBCCCBBBCCCBBBBBCCCCCBBBBBCCCBBCCCBBBCCCCCC
> BCCCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCBBBBBCCCCCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBACCSCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCCCCCCBCCC
> CBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCSSSSCCCCBCCCCBBBBCCBBBCCC
> CCBCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBBBCCCCCCBCCCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCCCBCCCCCCCCBBBBCCBCBCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCCCSCCCCB
> CCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCBACCSSSSCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCCCCCCBCCCCCBBCCCBCCCCCCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCB
> CCBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBACCCBBBCCCCBBCCCCCCCBBBCCBCCCCCCBBCCCCBBBCCBCCBCCBCC
> CBCCBBBBBCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCCCCBBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCBCCCCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCBC
> CBCCCCCBCBCCCBCCCBCCCCBCCCCBCCCCCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCBCCBBCCBCCBCCCCCB
> CCCCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBBCCCCBCBCBCCCCBCCCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBBBBCCCCBCCCCBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCB
> CCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCBCCCBBCBBCCCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCCCCBCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCABCCCBBBCCCCBBCCCCCCCBBBCCBBBBCCCBBCCCCBBBCCBCCBCCBCCCBCCBBBBBCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCBCC
> BCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCBCCCBCCBBBBBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBBBCCCBBBBCC
> BCCCBCCBBBBCCCBBCCCBCCCCCCCCCBBCCCCCCBBBCCCBBBBBCCBBBCCCBBBCCCBCCCCCBBBBCCCABCCBCCCBCCCCBCCCCBCCCCCBCCCC
> CCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCBBCCBCBCBCCCC
> BCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBBBCCCBBBBCCCBCBCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCBCCCCCCCCBBBBCCCCCBBBCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBBBB
> CCCAACCBBCBBCCCCBCCCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCBCBCCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCCCBCCCCBCCBCC
> BCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCCCCAACCBCCCBCCBBBBBCCBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCBCCCCBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCCBCCCCCBCC
> BCCBBBBBCCBBBCCCBBBCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCCBACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCBBBCCCBBBBBCCBCCCBCCBBBBBCCBCCCB
> CCCBBBCCCCCCBBBBBCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBBBBCCBBBBBCCBCCCBCCCBBCCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCBCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCC
> CBCCCCBCCCCBBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCBBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCB
> CCBBCCCCBCCCCCBCBCCCCCBCCCCBCBCBCCBCCBBCCCCCCCBCCCCBBBBCCBBBBCCCCCBBBBCCCCBCCCCBCBCBCCBBBBCCBCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCBBCCBCCCBCCCCBCCCCCBCBCCCCCBCCCCBCCBBCCBCCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBBCCBC
> CBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCCBBBCCCBBBBBCCCCBCCCCBBBBBCCBCCCBCCCBBBCCCCCCCCBCCCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCCCCC
> BBBBBCCBCCCBCCBCCBCCBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCC
> CBCCCBBCCCBBBCCCBBBCCCCCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBBCCBCCCBCCBBBBCCBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCBCCBCCBBC
> CBCCBCCCCCCCCBCCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCAACCBCCBCCBCBCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCBCBCCBCCBCCBBBCCCBCCBCCCCCBBBBCCBCBCBCCBBBBCCBCBCBCCBBBBCCBBBCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAACCBCCBCCBCCBBCCBCCCCCCCCBBCBBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCBCCCCCBCCBCCBCCBBCCCCCBCCBBCBBCCBCCCC
> CBCCBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCCBBCCCBCCCBCCBBBBCCCCCBCCCBCCCBBCCCBCCBCCBBBCCCCCCBCCBCCBCCCBCCBB
> BBCCBCCCBCCBBBBCCBCCBCCCCCCCCCCBCCCBCCCBCCCCCCCCCCCBACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBAABA
> ABBAABABABABABBABAAABBBAABBABBAABBABABABAABABAAAABAAABABAABAABBABABABBAABAAABABBABBAAAAAABAABBAAAAABAABB
> BAAAAAABBABA
> ```

I asked him what that was so supposed to mean but he just told me to work it out.

(Note: the original text didn't contain any paragraphs - I just added them for readability. If you want to copy that to work on it I suggest you copy the following original message:)

> ```
> 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
> ```

### What does this message say?

Comment: I think that the 367th C should be a B (just kidding... :P)

Comment: @Hunter :P don’t worry I am very sure this is correct. Even if one letter is off you should still be able to solve this (although it does depend which letter)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If we

> arrange the thing in rows of length 120, we find large letters made out of Bs amid Cs saying BORDERS ARE BACONIAN / START TOP LEFT AND / GO CLOCKWISE. THIS WILL REVEAL A RIDDLE / GIVING THE FINAL / ONE WORD ANSWER...
>
>  [image: Words]

That's

> preceded by some Baconian-looking stuff, which I actually looked at only after determining the foregoing. As it happens, it tells you to do what I already did above :-). More precisely, it says (spaces are obviously inserted by me): CONGRATULATIONS YOU HAUE SOLUED THE FIRST STEP NEXT REMOUE THIS MESSAGE AND USE A MONOSPACED FONT IN SIZE SIX ON THE REST THE LINE LENGTH IS ONE HUNDRED AND TWENTY IT WILL HELP REPLACING C WITH A SPACE.

So now we

> do what it says. We get: FRANCEISBACKONNOCABISINREUERSEFROMAPIGIDOCOMEWILLYOUSOLUETHISUERSE or, more comprehensibly,
>
> FRANCE IS BACK ON
> NO CAB IS IN REVERSE
> FROM A PIG I DO COME
> WILL YOU SOLVE THIS VERSE

which indicates that the word we need is simply

> BACON

since

> it consists of (1) a rough homophone of "FRANCIS BACON", (2) instructions to take "NO CAB" in reverse, and (3) the information that what we need comes from a pig.

Comment: Knowledge is power, France is bacon.

Comment: Does it actually say "CONGRATULATIONS YOU HAVE SOLUED"? Is that a typo from you, or the puzzle?

Comment: @Tas the baconIan cipher merges u and v - so when deciding the decoder Gareth uses chose to decode the cipher as a U. It should be a V but it doesn’t really matter